# Javascript error...cannot set property value of null

Tags: javascript

How should I correct this code? When it comes to document.getElementById....when do I use .value at the end?

```
 function processInput() {
if(i <= 5){
  listItem = "item" + i;
  document.getElementById("listItem").value = document.getElementById("toolBox").value;
  document.getElementById("toolbox") = "";
  if(i == 5){
    document.getElementById("resultsExpl") = "Thank you for your suggestions";
  }

  i += 1;
}
```

Comment: document.getElementById() returns the DOM Element. When you .value() a dom element, one of two things will happen.. if the dom element has a value attribute (like text fields or radio buttons,select element) then that value would be returned. If that is not the case, then the text between the starting and ending tags of the DOM element would be returned.

Comment: Now, try yourself and if there's a problem, make a jsfiddle and add it here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad assignments... that code looks hectic anyway and I dont know what does it need to do but try it again with something like this:

```
function processInput() {
    if(i <= 5){
        listItem = "item" + i;
        document.getElementById("listItem").value = document.getElementById("toolBox").value;
        document.getElementById("toolbox").textContent = "";
        if(i == 5){
            document.getElementById("resultsExpl").textContent = "Thank you for your suggestions";
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Or also try adding .value at the end instead of .textContent.

Answer (score 0):

The two lines is error:

`document.getElementById("toolbox") = "";
document.getElementById("resultsExpl") = "Thank you for your suggestions";`

those may modify to be:

`document.getElementById("toolbox").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("resultsExpl").innerHTML = "Thank you for your suggestions";`

If you want to set the content of a text input, you can use .value, and for other DOM, you may need the .innerHTML(set HTML content) or .innerText(set text content).

And you should check whether the dom you query with getElementById function exists or not.